# StreamBuilder cancel subscription on leave view port

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a CupertinoTabScaffold with 5 tabs one of them containing several StreamBuilder, The tabs are persisting which make the StreamBuilders are active all the time and sucking up memory and app performance. Is there a way to know if that tab is active or not to deactivate or cancel those streams subscription?

Comment: Isn't it achieved by reading the `tabBar.currentIndex` property ?

Comment: yes this is easy, I want to know how to cancel that StreamBuilder subscription of that widget, is there's any way to this?

Comment: You can't cancel a StreamBuilder subscription. If you want to control that list to the stream in `initState()` and store the returned subscription. You can then cancel this subscription.